# How to draw text on a bitmap in memory [no MFC]

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Can somebody explain how to draw text on a bitmap in memory?
I have the following code, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HDC buffDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    
    SelectObject(buffDC, hFnt);
    SetTextColor(buffDC, RGB(1, 1, 1));
    SetBkColor(buffDC, RGB(0, 255, 0));
    
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    HBITMAP buffBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(buffDC, rc.right, rc.bottom);

    int savedDC = SaveDC(buffDC);

    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    FillRect(buffDC, &rc, hBrush);
    DeleteObject(hBrush);

    //This is the part where I would like to draw to the bitmap
    TextOutA(buffDC, 0, 0, "Hello", 6);

    SelectObject(buffDC, buffBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, buffDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    RestoreDC(buffDC, savedDC);


    DeleteObject(buffBitmap);
    DeleteDC(buffDC);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

I have seen a lot of different solutions mostly using MFC, however I would like to avoid that approach if possible.

EDIT: I have checked the other already asked questions but I couldn't find one which would cover this without MFC.

My original problem was that I'm using a timer to call RedrawWindow and update the position of the text and make a sort of scrolling text which moves from right to left.

When I was in the testing process I have noticed that on some machines the app runs with up to 25% CPU usage and on some others it uses < 1%. I have tested the app one two machines with exactly the same specs running Windows 7 and the app ran on one with ~10% and the other with 0%.

(By the way my timer is getting called every 33ms and RedrawWindow uses RDW_UPDATENOW and I didn't handle the WM_ERASEBKGND message either :P
Since WM_TIMER (as far as I know) is a low priority message I was not concerned about the timer causing the issue with the CPU usage.)

I started to think that maybe I should be using a bitmap and BitBlt it to the screen rather than just simply drawing to the dc and updating the x coordinate every time I repaint the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can draw onto a bitmap, you have to select it into a memory device context.

Move `SelectObject(buffDC, buffBitmap);` before the first call to a drawing function, but usually as soon as possible after you created the bitmap.

In your sample code it appears suitable to insert it after the `SaveDC()` call so the original bitmap will be restored later when you call `RestoreDC()`:

```
int savedDC = SaveDC(buffDC);
SelectObject(buffDC, buffBitmap);
```

As commenters noted, `CreateCompatibleBitmap(buffDC, rc.right, rc.bottom)` should be changed to `CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom)`.
From the reference of [`CreateCompatibleBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1
>   monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is
>   used in CreateCompatibleBitmap, the bitmap that is created is a
>   monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used
>   to create the memory device context

Finally a suggestion: If you just need a *temporary* bitmap (as in your sample code), there is a more efficient API available since Windows Vista. It is called the **buffered paint API**. MSDN does not appear to provide a good overview, here is a [tutorial](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/vista/article.php/c15709/Using-Windows-Vista-BuiltIn-Double-Buffering.htm) and the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486120(v=vs.85).aspx) (all functions that have "BufferedPaint" in their name).

Comment: `CreateCompatibleBitmap(buffDC, rc.right, rc.bottom)` should be changed to `CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom)`

Comment: Otherwise, you are creating a monochrome bitmap. A device context when created has initially selected a 1x1px monochrome bitmap selected into it. At any rate, that question has been asked a bazillion times. Better close as a duplicate than trying to provide an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm glad to close vote if you could provide a suitable dupe. So far I have not found one that matches this particular problem.

Comment: Thanks zett42 I will check out the links you have posted above.

Comment: I have also edited the original post to give a better overview on the issue I'm facing. Unfortunately I can't post the original code though, however I hope you will get what I meant.

Comment: As with all questions that have more than one issue, it is hard to find a good duplicate. A [mcve] would have helped to isolate either issue. So would a good question title.

Comment: Thanks for the advices not only on solving the issue but also on how to ask efficiently. It seems that the above answer provides the solution to both issues I had. I'm posting the code bellow which worked for me as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Window Procedure which worked for me and is based on the answer from zett42.
This piece of code is just for testing purposses as I cannot post the original source code of the application I'm working on due to work.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   static int xPos;
   const bool bIsBufferedPaint = true;
   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_CREATE:
   {
      BufferedPaintInit();
   }
   break;
   case WM_PAINT:
      {
         PAINTSTRUCT ps;
         HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
         if(bIsBufferedPaint)
         {
            HDC newDC;
            RECT rc;
            RECT dstrc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            dstrc = rc;
            dstrc.left = rc.right + xPos;
            HPAINTBUFFER hBufferedPaint = BeginBufferedPaint(hdc, &rc, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, NULL, &newDC);
            if(hBufferedPaint)
            {
                BufferedPaintClear(hBufferedPaint, NULL);
                SetTextColor(newDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                DrawText(newDC, L"Using buffered paint", -1, &dstrc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER | DT_LEFT);
                Sleep(2);
                EndBufferedPaint(hBufferedPaint, TRUE);

            }
            else
            {
            // buffer paint did not work.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HDC buffDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            SetTextColor(buffDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetBkColor(buffDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));

            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            HBITMAP buffBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);

            int savedDC = SaveDC(buffDC);
            SelectObject(buffDC, buffBitmap);

            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
            FillRect(buffDC, &rc, hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);
            std::string testText = "Not using the buffered paint API";
            TextOutA(buffDC, xPos, 0, testText.c_str(), testText.size());
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, buffDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            RestoreDC(buffDC, savedDC);

            DeleteObject(buffBitmap);
            DeleteDC(buffDC);
         }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
   case WM_ERASEBKGND:
       return 1;
    case WM_TIMER:
        {
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case TIMER1:
            {
                xPos--;
                RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE | RDW_ERASE);
                if(bIsBufferedPaint)
                {
                    if(xPos <= -500)
                        xPos = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(xPos <= -50)
                        xPos = 1000;
                }

            }
            break;
        }
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    {
         BufferedPaintUnInit();
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:

        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```